# Polkadot consensus and Honey Badger BFT

Tags: consensus

I want to know the relationship between Polkadot consensus and Honey Badger BFT (HBBFT). Is Polkadot's consensus using HBBFT?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Polkadot's consensus doesn't use HBBFT. When the original vision paper was written (https://polkadot.network/PolkaDotPaper.pdf), it was mentioned as a possible component or inspiration for research to be done later. But Polkadot ended up using a custom hybrid consensus mechanism composed of [BABE](https://polkadot.network/blog/polkadot-consensus-part-3-babe/) and [GRANDPA](https://polkadot.network/blog/polkadot-consensus-part-2-grandpa/). Neither of these use threshold encryption or are asynchronously live (which is the hallmark of HBBFT).

Comment: thank you very much